# Protecting client data

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

A little background.  We have a web based system that allows clients to enter/upload confidential data.  We are currently using SQL Server 2005 and Column Level Encryption.  The user creates a key
that's used to encrypt their data(encryptbypassphrase function in SQL).  We do not store their key anywhere. If the user loses or forgets their key somehow, we can't help retrieve their data. The main reasoning behind this encryption is so that if we get a Freedom of Information request we will only be handing over encrypted data because we don't have the decryption key.

There are a number of drawbacks to this method though. We have to maintain multiple environments (encrypted and un-encrypted). We also need to maintain multiple copies of stored procedures (encrypted vs un-encrypted). We can never refresh the dev or qa environments with production data because because those environments are not encrypted while production is.  Debugging prod issues are a nightmare because we can't see the encrypted data, and we can't refresh a qa 
environment and try to reproduce the issue.  The encrypted fields have to varbinary max and it's quite a few fields so space and performance take a huge hit.  Queries with encrypted fields
and lots of joins take a long time.

My question is how can we protect client data in such a way that we the holder of that data can't see it.  But don't have the above drawbacks.  I know SQL 2008 introduced Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) but that wouldn't work for us because we would hold the key.  I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Your question does not provide a lot of detail about constraints you have but one option would be to do the encryption / decryption in the app tier instead of in the stored procedures. That way you would at least not need to have different sets of sprocs for encrypted / unencrypted. It would also be easier to control encrypted/unencrypted through configuration in the app tier. However the issue with not being able to restore Prod to QA would be there with any solution in which you do not have the key to the encrypted data.

Comment: Why maintain two environments (encrypted vs not)? You can stuff plaintext into a varbinary field with no problem. Tack on a column that says whether the data is encrypted or not and have your access layer (stored procedures etc) do the right thing based on that. That is, if it's encrypted, run decryption. If it's not, just cast it back to (n)varchar. By doing it this way, you don't have to maintain two sets of code.

Comment: Also, don't be so sure that you're providing the level of protection you think you are. You're trying to protect against a FOI request? What prevents our benevolent overlords from ordering you to to a trace wherein you sniff the password on the wire? Anytime you have a safe that you need to hand someone the key to unlock, the key can be copied in transit.

Comment: I agree @ben thul, the key can certainly be captured and stored.  This app was written prior to my arrival at the company.  The business seems to think this is the most secure way of protecting client data.  I've been skeptical and am looking for ways to convince management to use different less problematic encryption methods.

Comment: Also @BenThul you're right about the two environments.  I'm not sure why that was done but I will recommend going forward that there be only one environment - encrypted.

Comment: @user469104 I'm not sure how decryption in the code would work as the data is encrypted using SQL's built in function encrptbypassphrase.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Acrylic Without any examples/details it is somewhat hard to recommend a really great approach but i'd say user469104 is pointing to the right track -> the most 'secure' way of doing things is not always operationally manageable and comes with a cost overhead (that you're experiencing). What i'd try and convince the management in would be that the same level of security of customer data can be achieve with way less overhead. For example, RSA cryptography could be of great help -> you'd only have the consumers have the private keys and voila.

Comment: @zaitsman sorry for the late response.  I had to do a bit of reading up on RSA encryption in sql server.  Based on what I'm reading that method (encryptbyasymkey) is actually the slowest and has the most overhead.  We are still looking at all options and any input is appreciated.

Comment: @Acrylic is it a requirement to manage encyption inside the db? Because that is actually less secure - typically you'd have the encryption done in the app and rhen if the mdf file is stolen it is useless as the keys were not with it. So for you it will address the main requirement - keys with the customer, encrypted data with the hoster